# SQL response type

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In my application I get an SQL query from user then I send to a db. Can I get information about what is the result type of SQL query is without parsing the query? I use pure JDBC to do these operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use a `PreparedStatement` and invoke its `getMetadata` method in order to have information about the `ResultSet`s columns it will return.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getMetaData()

```
Connection conn = ...
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(yourStatement);
ResultSetMetadata metadata = ps.getMetadata(); // this is what you need
...
// now you can execute the query
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `connection.prepareStatement()` on your query, a `preparedStatement` is returned. Use its [`.getMetaData()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getMetaData%28%29).