# SQL request type

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

This question is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585144/sql-response-type). It is good that I can get MetaData. However reading the documentation I have understood that this data is only for SELECT type requests. And I need more information, is it UPDATE or SELECT and etc. Can I get this information without parsing SQL request? What will be if I use executeQuery() or getMetaData()  to UPDATE or DELETE request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta data is available only on [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29) and [`Database`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29) level but not on `Update` and `Delete` type of queries. The [`Statement.execute( String sql )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) can be used to identify if the query returns `ResultSet(s)` or an integer amount of records affected.

Documentation says:
*The execute method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of the first result. You must then use the methods `getResultSet` or `getUpdateCount` to retrieve the result, and `getMoreResults` to move to any subsequent result(s).*

This method returns *`true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results`*

There is no any direct method that tells you if the query being is used is an `Update` or a `Delete`. You require to parse it explicit and identify.

Comment: In addition to ResultSet and Database level metadata, you also have Parameter level metadata [`getParameterMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getParameterMetaData()) although that metadata also doesn't help for the problem :)